# ScrollView won't scroll to the bottom

Tags: java, android

When i test my app on Nexus 5 emulator in android studio it works fine, when i test it on my Samsung Galaxy S6 it also works fine, but when i test it on my old Sony Xperia L it won't let me scroll to the bottom.
I mean, the scroll bar on the right looks like it's on the bottom but it's not, i can't see all items from ListView.
Heres my XML code:

```
/<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/scrollView"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView9"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">

    <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView9"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">

        <ListView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="460dp"
            android:id="@+id/listView"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView9"
            android:layout_below="@+id/scrollView"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    </TableLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

This is how it looks like:
http://postimg.org/image/qwb8iqarn/

If i remove the 6th line (android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView9") then i can scroll to the bottom, but, as you can probably guess, the design gets messed up because the items from the list go past the line (textView9)

Comment: why you are putting `ListView` inside `ScrollView` as `ListView` is already scrollable

Comment: Thanks Nilesh, i didn't know that listview was scrollable, it works now ^^